# checking if radio is selected with jquery does not satisfy condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to detect if a radio button is checked like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("#id_weight_goal_type_1").is(':checked')) { alert("1 its checked"); }

});
```

My html looks like:

```
<input checked="checked" class="rd-input" id="id_weight_goal_type_1" name="weight_goal_type" type="radio" value="1" />
```

The problem is that the alert never fires.  Is my syntax wrong?  In other example this is wrapped in a change function, but I want this to check on page load.

There are no console errors.

Comment: Any javascript errors when you debug with Developer Tools?

Comment: Your posted HTML and jQuery works for me: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jyLcb2nz/); so what's different in your live page?

Comment: [Nothing wrong with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/q92vtbp8/). There are extenuating circumstances not being shown here, such as: javascript errors, a lack of the jquery library, other libraries conflicting with jQuery requiring `$` to be namespaced with `jQuery(function($){`..etc

Comment: Your code looks good, however the way you have it implemented it will only execute once, when the document loads. If you want to detect when the state of radio buttons changes between checked and unchecked you will need to bind to an event for the radio button, perhaps the click event for example.

Comment: You are targeting the element by the #id, is there a chance that there is another element with this id on your page? As stated above, your code works, and your code works for me also. Also, make sure that your element exists (is in the DOM) when the javascript is run. try `console.log($("#id_weight_goal_type_1"));` and make sure the element that is logged is the element you are expecting.

Comment: This code is working for me. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zyrwkas/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I turned off alerts in Chrome.

Doing this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("#id_weight_goal_type_1").is(':checked')) { console.log("1 its checked"); }

});
```